# Mass setup Android 6.0 phones

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

We are ahead of a task to setup 100's (hundreds) of Android 6.0 phones.

Is there a way this task could be made easier?

Basically every phone when you turn it on asks you things like: language, WiFi, Google account.

And we would like to make that task easier/quicker.

Also we would like to install an app on the phones as well. (Play Store app).

Any ideas?

Regards
Elemer

Comment: Wouldn't the google accounts all be different?

Comment: Yes, definitely a new account for each user/phone. - This will be a tricky one as well, last time we had a similar task after a few new google accounts were setup google made us click "I am not a robot" , I presume because they were having a lot of new accounts created from the same IP address which raised some "eyebrowes" .

Comment: The fact you have separate Google accounts is going to make this really tricky.